# Draw a GeoJson map polygon and extract the coordinates to a python list or a json file

Tags: python, json, list, polygon, geojson

Dear Stackoverflow community. I need to know how to build a GeoJson map that allows me to draw a polygon and add the coordinates of this drawed polygon to a python list or a json file.

I have been reading all kind of documentation but I didn´t find anything like I´m searching.
If anybody could help me with code or specific documentation, I would be great for me!!!!!
Thanks a lot.
Pablo.

Comment: Hi! What exactly do you mean by draw?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me explain you with an example.

1. You have a common map made it with folium. Now I need to know how to do the next two points:
2. I need to know how click on the map and “draw” a polygon or shape.
   I can "draw" the polygon or any shape, but with a python script specifying the coordinates (latitude and longitude). I don't want that, I want to draw the polygon by clicking on the map.
3. Finally, I want the polygon coordinates to be automatically added to a python list or a json script.

I hope I was clear explaining the problem.